# How can I edit my regex so that it captures only the substring between (and not including) quotation marks?

Tags: r, regex

I'm a total novice to regex, and have a hard time wrapping my head around it. Right now I have a column filled with strings, but the only relevant text to my analysis is between quotation marks. I've tried this:

```
response$text <-  stri_extract_all_regex(response$text, '"\\S+"')
```

but when I view response$text, the output comes out like this:

```
"\"caring\""
```

How do I change my regex expression so that instead the output reads:

```
caring
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringi)
response$text <- stri_extract_all_regex(response$text, '(?<=")[^\\s"]+(?=")')
```

Or, with `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)
response$text <- str_extract_all(response$text, '(?<=")[^\\s"]+(?=")')
```

However, with several words inside quotes, I'd rather use `stringr::str_match_all`:

```r
library(stringr)
matches <- str_match_all(response$text, '"([^\\s"]+)"')
response$text <- lapply(matches, function(x) x[,2])
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BCb6Uh/1).

With the capturing group approach used in `"([^\\s"]+)"` it becomes possible to avoid overlapping matches between quoted substrings, and `str_match_all` becomes handy since the matches it returns contain the captured substrings as well (unlike `*extract*` functions).